# I spilled some milk on MacBook Pro, there is no sound what should I do?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, damage

I spilled some milk on my MacBook Pro and immediately dried it, it seemed to only have been on the top and bottom. Then about 10 minutes later I played a movie and there was no sound. I then noticed a small amount of milk in the aux port so I sucked it out and turned it off and started drying it off (I turned it upside down and put it in front of my now barely warm fire place.) What should do for the sound to be normal?

Comment: the main issue is there is no sound everything else seems to be fine

Answer (score -1):

As a home remedy, you can soak your macbook in a packet of rice. it will absorb the excess water droplet in a safe manner. In that case sometime you might be able save some money without de-assembling your macbook. If any case the issue is there continuously, you better meet a technician or if you are still inside the warranty period, better do the steps adhering that.
Soaking in a rice bucket has been experimented successfully with my xiaomi phone and my hp envy laptop (water spoiled).

Comment: any valid reason for the down vote? I would really like to have a comment after the downvote of the answer